# Setting up Discourse on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rails-migrations, hstore, discourse

I have setup a new database for installing Discourse in PostgreSQL. When I run rake db:migrate, it creates most of the tables, but it then fails:

```
-- execute("INSERT INTO archetypes (name_key, created_at, updated_at) VALUES ('poll', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)")
   -> 0.0009s
-- add_column(:forum_threads, :archetype_id, :integer, {:default=>1, :null=>false})
   -> 0.0209s
==  CreateArchetypes: migrated (0.0424s) ======================================

==  AddMetaDataToForumThreads: migrating ======================================
-- execute("CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore")
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::Error: ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/hstore.control": No such file or directory
: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/MiniProfiler-d149f34fcdb6/Ruby/lib/patches/sql_patches.rb:155:in `exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/MiniProfiler-d149f34fcdb6/Ruby/lib/patches/sql_patches.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:652:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:458:in `method_missing'
/root/discourse/db/migrate/20120921162512_add_meta_data_to_forum_threads.rb:3:in `change'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:407:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:407:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:129:in `with_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:389:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:179:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It appears from the database error "could not open extension control file" while trying to `CREATE EXTENSION [...] hstore` that the extension `hstore` is not installed.

On Ubuntu, you can install the extension by installing the `postgresql-contrib` package.

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib
```

User terryjray has documented [enabling hstore](https://gist.github.com/terryjray/3296171) in a Gist.

Comment: I am, however, a sudoer, and I should be able to install it.

Comment: I may also add that I ran this as root and the db user. Sorry for comment spam.

Comment: Check your user role on your database. I'm guessing you're not a superuser db-user-wise. The [Ubuntu pg guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL) might be helpful for help setting up your db-user roles.

Comment: This solution didn't work on Ubuntu 13.04 with Postgresql 9.2 as Postgres APT repo doesn't fully support Ubuntu 13.04. To get the postgresql-contrib-9.2 to install I first had to run the shell script that's linked to in the wiki [link](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt) - run it using parameter "precise" for Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: I got error while installing ```postgresql-contrib``` ```/var/run/postgresql/.s.pgsql.5432.lock permission denied```
So I gave permissions like this ```sudo chown -R postgres:postgres /var/run/postgresql```

Answer (score 2):

If you have two `Postgresql` installation on your ubuntu such as `9.1` and `9.3`

Before running the version specific installation, you may need to add the correct postgres repo using their [instructions](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt) which I'm paraphrasing below in case they disappear:

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ UBUNTU_VERSION_NAME-pgdg main
sudo apt-get install wget ca-certificates
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
apt-get update
```

(UBUNTU_VERSION_NAME should be replaced by trusty or whatever your version name is)

then you can use commands below to install the `hstore` extension on each server separately:

**Postgresql 9.1:**

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.1
```

**Postgresql 9.3:**

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib
```